# Enterprise Library exception block, System.Exception type handlers overide other exception types handler

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, enterprise-library, faultcontract

I am using the Enterprise Library exception handling block.

I have the following issue:

I want to have a policy with two exception types (`optimisticconcurencyexception` and `system.exceptions`). For the `optimisticconcurencyexception` I add a fault handler. For `system.exceptions` I add a different fault handler and a logging handler.

Now if i catch the `optimisticconcurencyexception`  the library will execute the `system.exceptions` fault handler and logging handler and not just the fault handler that i assigned for `optimisticconcurencyexception`

I set a breakpoint in the debugger where the exception manager processes the method that throw's the `optimisticconcurencyexception`,  and in code, i get the right `faultexception`.

Am i understandable? Any thoughts on this issue?

## EDIT

My question was anwsered on the enterprise library support forum.

Here is a link  http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/349033